# Visualising interaction between two categorical predictors and continuous outcome with ribbon confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R, so apologise in advance for a possible simple or obvious question.

I am trying to graph an interaction between two categorical variables (A and I), which both have 2 levels (0 and 1), against one continuous variable (V). I would like V on the Y axes, A on the X axes and I as different lines on the graph. However, I would like to include 95% confidence intervals. I would like to use a ribbon style CI on the graph (like geom_ribbon produces). However, I cannot do this after identifying A and I as binary categorical variables in R. The only way I can figure out how to do it is leaving A as a continuous variable (see picture). The syntax I am using is below:

```
data$I <- as.factor(data$I)
data$A <- as.factor(data$A)

gp <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=A, y=V, colour=I)) 
gp + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

Though I did not set A as a categorical variable when producing the attached image.

[image]

Comment: I don't think such a visualization is well-defined. How do you define a 95% CI partway between `A == 0` and `A == 1`, when `A` itself cannot take on such values as a categorical variable? I don't know the context of your application, but to me, it seems a better way to visualize your data is with `geom_boxplot()`, which will display the full distribution for all combinations of factors.

Comment: I like [ggridges](https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/) for this; you can shade the CI.